# how to get id of a dropped element - jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have tried many ways to get the id of dropped element in jquery UI. please help to get the value of id.

```
$( function() {    

    $(".draggable").draggable({
        revert: "invalid",      
        helper: "clone"     
    });

$( "#droppable2" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            var draggable = ui.draggable;           
            var dragged = draggable.clone(); 
            var currentID = ui.draggable.attr("id");/*draggable.find('id'); - returns an object. but, could not get the id. */

            alert(dragged.html());          
            alert(currentID);
            dragged.resizable();
            dragged.appendTo("#droppable2");

            //alert("open properties");
      }
    });

  } );
```

html of the dropped element returns and it contains the id.

---html---

```
<div class="ui-widget-content draggable">
                <select id='singleSelect'>
                  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                </select>
            </div>

<div id='droppable2' class="ui-widget-header" height='100%'><p/></div>
```

Comment: Your markup is weird...what is this `<p/>`? ... in `<div id='droppable2' class="ui-widget-header" height='100%'><p/></div>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to find the `select` first and then get its `id`, because `ui.draggable` returns a **[nodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList)**, also as I said in my comment, you are using a `<p>` tag wrong, corrected that a bit:

```js
$(function() {

  $(".draggable").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: "clone"
  });

  $("#droppable2").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var draggable = ui.draggable;
      var dragged = draggable.clone();
      var currentID = ui.draggable.find('select').attr('id');
      console.log(currentID);
      dragged.resizable();
      dragged.appendTo("#droppable2");

      //alert("open properties");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget-content draggable">
  <select id='singleSelect'>
                  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                </select>
</div>

<div id='droppable2' class="ui-widget-header" height='100%'>
  <p>some paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to share that you can simply use this code to get id/class name of a dropped element:

```
ui.draggable.attr("yourid/yourclass");
```

add this code inside your droppable function.